# bsd gcc preprocessor macro ##x## doesn't give a valid preprocessing token

Tags: c, macos, gcc, macros

when i try to compile i got tons of those error :

```
km6502ot.h:77:1: error: pasting "Opcodei" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

I'm on OSX, i can solve it by doing it manually for all possibilities but is it possible to fix this macro so gcc would eat it peacefully :

```
#define OP__(i) \
    case 0x##i##: \
        Opcode##i##(__THISP); \
        break;
#define OP_d(i) \
    case 0x##i##: \
        if (__THIS__.P & D_FLAG) \
            D_Opco##i##(__THISP); \
        else \
            Opcode##i##(__THISP); \
        break;
```

Comment: i'm trying to compile http://www.neshq.com/nsf/xmms-nsf-0.0.3.tar.gz btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
#define OP__(i) \
    case 0x##i : \
        Opcode##i (__THISP); \
        break;
#define OP_d(i) \
    case 0x##i : \
        if (__THIS__.P & D_FLAG) \
            D_Opco##i (__THISP); \
        else \
            Opcode##i (__THISP); \
        break;
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between "##x##" and "##x " ?

Comment: @user3232170 `##` This makes the identifier. It is not connected `(` etc. identifier created because should not be invalid.